# BeautifulSoup: How do I get different items from a <div>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been messing with BeautifulSoup to scrape a website.
The structure is as such:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="cf-listing"><time></div>
    <a class="post-title" href="http://example.com">This is example</a>
    <div class="cf-listing"><time></div>
    <a class="post-title" href="http://example.com">This is example</a>
    .....
</div>
```

This is after I used `soup.find_all("div", class_="content")`. I have created three empty arrays called "time", "post-title" and "url" which I want to append with , a.text, a.href

I am trying to use for-each loop but I am not sure how to target specific item with BeautifulSoup.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
one = soup.find_all("div", class_="content")
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's a better idea to post your code in addition to explaining what it does

Comment: ```soup.select('div item_name')``` should work. And ```item_name``` is the item you want to search. Here you are using ```select.find_all```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `soup.select()` or `soup.find_all()` to select all `<div class="cf-listing">`  and then `.find_next('a')` to select next '' tag.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="content">
    <div class="cf-listing">This is time 1</div>
    <a class="post-title" href="http://example1.com">This is example 1</a>
    <div class="cf-listing">This is time 2</div>
    <a class="post-title" href="http://example2.com">This is example 2</a>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

time_lst, href_lst, title_lst = [], [] , []
for div in soup.select('.cf-listing'):
    time_lst.append( div.get_text(strip=True) )
    href_lst.append( div.find_next('a')['href'] )
    title_lst.append( div.find_next('a').get_text(strip=True) )

# print it to screen:
for t, href, title in zip(time_lst, href_lst, title_lst):
    print('{:<30}{:<30}{}'.format(t, href, title))
```

Prints:

```
This is time 1                http://example1.com           This is example 1
This is time 2                http://example2.com           This is example 2
```

Comment: This answered my question! Thank you.